# How would I read the data from a fanatec wheel base and print the according values?

Tags: python, libusb

I want to make a simple HUD for OBS that has that shows wheel rotation, gas, brake and clutch movemnt but I need to figure out how to read the values first. I am using a fanatec wheel base model v2.5 and its connected via USB. I have the PID and VID and want to go on from there but I really have no idea how to do it.

I have tried using python with usb.core and usb.util libaries but I dont I cant get it to work. I got a backend error even though I have set up my backend using pywinusb. I really dont know where to start so some help would be appritiated.